# Adding gas to address generated at run time

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency, go-ethereum

I am tinkering with a piece of code that creates keys and addresses.
When I run the code I get the following error.

> insufficient funds for gas * price + value

My question is, how can I get `funds` into this address?

Any suggestions?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/jimlawless/whereami"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/xyz")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + "@" + err.Error() + " @ " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA("fad9c8855b740a0b7ed4c221dbad0f33a83a49cad6b3fe8d5817ac83d38b6a19")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + "@" + err.Error() + " @ " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("error casting public key to ECDSA")
    }

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA)
    fmt.Print("fromAddress: ")
    fmt.Println(fromAddress)
    nonce, err := client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + "@" + err.Error() + " @ " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    value := big.NewInt(0)      // in wei (0 eth)
    gasLimit := uint64(2000000) // in units
    gasPrice, err := client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + "@" + err.Error() + " @ " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    toAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x4592d8f8d7b001e72cb26a73e4fa1806a51ac79d")
    tokenAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x28b149020d2152179873ec60bed6bf7cd705775d")

    transferFnSignature := []byte("transfer(address,uint256)")
    hash := sha3.NewLegacyKeccak256()
    hash.Write(transferFnSignature)
    methodID := hash.Sum(nil)[:4]
    fmt.Println(hexutil.Encode(methodID)) // 0xa9059cbb

    paddedAddress := common.LeftPadBytes(toAddress.Bytes(), 32)
    fmt.Println(hexutil.Encode(paddedAddress)) // 0x0000000000000000000000004592d8f8d7b001e72cb26a73e4fa1806a51ac79d

    amount := new(big.Int)
    amount.SetString("1000000000000000000000", 10) // 1000 tokens
    paddedAmount := common.LeftPadBytes(amount.Bytes(), 32)
    fmt.Println(hexutil.Encode(paddedAmount)) // 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003635c9adc5dea00000

    var data []byte
    data = append(data, methodID...)
    data = append(data, paddedAddress...)
    data = append(data, paddedAmount...)

    tx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, tokenAddress, value, gasLimit, gasPrice, data)
    signedTx, err := types.SignTx(tx, types.HomesteadSigner{}, privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + "@" + err.Error() + " @ " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    err = client.SendTransaction(context.Background(), signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + "@" + err.Error() + " @ " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    fmt.Printf("tx sent: %s", signedTx.Hash().Hex()) // tx sent: 0xa56316b637a94c4cc0331c73ef26389d6c097506d581073f927275e7a6ece0bc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get funds on the account, you transfer them from another account that already has funds. This depends on the network or the execution environment where you deploy your accounts.

[In the case of Rinkerby testnet, you transfer them from the developer faucet](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/).

Comment: When I tweeted https://twitter.com/pigfoxeria/status/1488672478129909762 then went to https://faucet.rinkeby.io and added the url and clicked give me ether I got the following error "insufficient funds for gas * price + value" from https://faucet.rinkeby.io

Comment: If you have another question please open another question. I am not Rikerby user support in SO comments.